# Randomly select command to execute?

Tags: powershell, random, command, invoke

Idea: I want to change the time randomly using `set-date`'s three options, `.AddHours()`, `.AddMinutes()`, `.AddSeconds()`. My first thought was storing them in an array and referencing them randomly but it's  not executing. It's just storing the string printing instead of executing it.

Code so far:

```
$test = "Set-Date -Date (Get-Date).AddHours($\(Get-Random -Maximum 25))", "Set-Date -Date (Get-Date).AddSeconds($\(Get-Random -Maximum 61))", "Set-Date -Date (Get-Date).AddMinutes($\(Get-Random -Maximum 61))"
```

Output:

```
$Test
```

> ```
> Set-Date -Date (Get-Date).AddHours(22)
> Set-Date -Date (Get-Date).AddSeconds($\(Get-Random -Maximum 61))
> Set-Date -Date (Get-Date).AddMinutes($\(Get-Random -Maximum 61))
> ```

```
$test[0]
```

> ```
> Set-Date -Date (Get-Date).AddHours(22)
> ```

```
$(Get-Random -InputObject $test)
```

> ```
> Set-Date -Date (Get-Date).AddMinutes($\(Get-Random -Maximum 61))
> ```

If there is another way to do this, if you need further explanation, or if there are any other questions, feel free to ask :) THANK YOU!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use, invoke-expression/command.

Comment: Invoke-Expression worked but & "String" did not. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

- **Use *script blocks* (`{ ... }`) to store arbitrary commands in variables**. Invoke script blocks on demand with `&`, the call operator.
- A few asides:

  - Don't use `\` as the escape character - PowerShell expects `` ` `` instead.
  - To execute full commands stored in *strings*, you need `Invoke-Expression`; however, [`Invoke-Expression` is rarely the right tool, and is a security risk - avoid it whenever possible](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).
- `$(...)`, the subexpression operator is only needed (a) inside *expandable strings* (`"..."`) and generally to enclose *multiple* statements; outside of an expandable string, as part of an expression, you do *not* need it for single commands such as `Get-Random -Maximum 25 - enclosing the command in` (...)` is enough.
- `&`, the call operator, executes a *command name/path* stored in a string, not a whole command *line* (a command plus arguments). It is also used to invoke *script blocks*.

Note: I've replaced `Set-Date` with `Get-Date` in the commands below so that experimenting with them doesn't cause side effects.

```
# Store the commands in an array of script blocks.
$test = { Get-Date -Date (Get-Date).AddHours((Get-Random -Maximum 25)) }, 
        { Get-Date -Date (Get-Date).AddSeconds((Get-Random -Maximum 61)) }, 
        { Get-Date -Date (Get-Date).AddMinutes((Get-Random -Maximum 61)) }

# Select a random command and execute it using &
& (Get-Random $test)
```

Performance note: For better performance, the array of input objects to randomly select an element from, `$test`, is passed as a *direct argument* here (implicitly binds to the `-InputObject` parameter) rather than *via the pipeline* (`$test | Get-Random`). For small arrays, the difference will be negligible, but with larger ones it matters. Do note, however, that cmdlets often do *not* accept arrays *as a whole* as arguments, in which case the pipeline must be used - see [GitHub issue #4242](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4242).

Comment: Nice update. Is the performance dif based on the length of the list or does the complexity of the script blocks factor into it?

Comment: @Phillyclause89: it's only about the element count of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some ways to do this that don't involve generating code in strings.

First, let's select a random method of the 3 methods you want, then invoke it!

```
$now = Get-Date
$value = Get-Random -Maximum 61
$method = $now.AddSeconds,$now.AddMinutes,$now.AddHours | Get-Random
Set-Date -Date $method.Invoke($value)
```

This doesn't account for different maximums depending on time unit, but it may give you some food for thought.

Consider also that a DateTime object has an `.Add()` method that takes a `[TimeSpan]` object, so you could also just pre-calculate a timespan, then use `$now.Add($timespan)`.

It's not clear from your question why you want to alternate between hours minutes and seconds, so if I make the assumption that you're trying to just change the date to be some random amount of time in the future that's less than or equal to 24 hours, your issue becomes much simpler:

```
$offset = Get-Random -Maximum 86400   # or 86401 if you want
$timespan = New-TimeSpan -Seconds $offset
Set-Date -Adjust $timespan
```

and you can see in this case that you can use the `-Adjust` parameter instead of getting the current date and manually calling its `.Add()` method.

If you must toggle between offset units, let's try choosing random hashtables and using those as parameters to `New-TimeSpan`:

```
$chaos = @(
    @{ Seconds = (Get-Random -Maximum 61) } ,
    @{ Minutes = (Get-Random -Maximum 61) } ,
    @{ Hours = (Get-Random -Maximum 25) }
) | Get-Random
$timespan = New-TimeSpan @chaos
Set-Date -Adjust $timespan
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the invocation operator on the string. Or, I do not fully understand your requirements.

```
& $test[0]
```

Comment: '&' doesn't work but for future reference, "Invoke-Expression" does work! thanks anyway!

Comment: `&` only works with command _names or paths_, not with full command lines; `& "cmd" /c echo hi` works (the arguments are specified _separately_), `& "cmd /c echo hi"` does not.